# xslt xsl:result-document overwrites file

Tags: java, xml, xslt

Hi everyone i have xsl script, which converts xml to csv and save result to files via `<xsl:result-document href="file:///C:/****/*****/result-case.txt" method="text">`, but i have a problem. After each xml transformation it overwrite result file and i lose result from previous transformation. How can i transform 100000 xml ,and get all data in one file? 
I am using xsl version 2.0.

Comment: Append some time part or some element position() for uniq combination or you can concat filename with generate_id fuction will generate uniq combination

Comment: and if i process 1000 xml files i will have 1000 files?

Comment: you can process as much file as you want.

Comment: i have to get only one output file with all data from 1000 xml, not 1000 files

Comment: Update xsl file result document like: `<xsl:result-document href="{concat('file:///C:/****/*****/result-case',generate-id(),'.txt')}" method="text">`

Comment: Done, i tried to transform 1000 xml files and get 1000 result files, but i need only 1 file with all data. https://imgur.com/a/Lekto18

Comment: In this case it might be better to not have the XSL create the file. Instead have the xsl create the csv content per file and then write/append to file using java?

Comment: It is unclear what it means to have "all data in one file". Please show minimal examples for your input XML documents (at least two), minimal XSLT stylesheet code and the expected output. Thanks.

Comment: @ophychius using java also overwrites file after transformation

Comment: @MathiasMüller "all data in one file" for example after xml transformation i have result one line in csv format. Now, if i transform 1000 xml files i got one line in my file, because after each xml transformation file overwrites. I want so after transforming 1000 xml files i got 1000 lines in my file. In a hour i can show xml and xsl but xml is deeeply nested and his size is 3000-100000 lines

Comment: Please show minimal examples for all files and code, only what is necessary. Thanks. Without knowing more, you should probably store the returned line of CSV in a Java string and write to a file in Java, as @ophychius has suggested.

Comment: @MathiasMüller i dont really understand how my xml helps you,if i have another problem. I show xsl and i hope you don't need to see csv file? .  About 1 line it is example. After one transformation it can be 500 lines output. At my xsl you can see that output stored to 3 different files that is another problem, that is why i can not use java, i think

Answer (score 1):

In general, with XSLT 2 or 3, if you want to create a transformation that transforms several files to single result, I would suggest to start with a named template; in XSLT 3 for that you have `xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template"`, in XSLT 2 you need use any template name you want to use as an entry point e.g. `xsl:template name="main"`.

As for the input documents, depending on the processor you might be able to use the `uri-collection` (XSLT 3) or at least the `collection` function (XSLT 2) to process a collection of input documents e.g. in Saxon 9 to process all `.xml` documents from a certain directory you can use e.g. `uri-collection('file:/root/dir/subdir/?select=*.xml')`.

You can then push such a collection to your existing templates, you only have to make sure you use your `xsl:result-document` once e.g.

```
<xsl:param name="folder-uri" as="xs:string">file:/root/dir/subdir/</xsl:param>

<xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
  <xsl:result-document href="result.csv" method="text">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="uri-collection($folder-uri || '?select=*.xml') ! doc(.)/*"/>
  </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
```

To run such transformation starting with a named template I would suggest to move away from the JAXP API that expects a single source and use an API designed to work with XSLT 2 or 3, i.e. in the case of Saxon 9 the s9api with `XsltTransformer` (http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/XsltTransformer.html#setInitialTemplate-net.sf.saxon.s9api.QName-) or `Xslt30Transformer` (http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/Xslt30Transformer.html#callTemplate-net.sf.saxon.s9api.QName-net.sf.saxon.s9api.Destination-).